# cellforRowAtIndexPath isn't called but numberOfRows and numberOfsection are called

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have been trying for almost a day now , i have a table view and i call reload data to reload the entries of table. CellForRowAtIndexPath is called only first time but after that other 2 functions number of rows and number of sections are called but not cellforRow. I have checked rows and sections are non - zero and links are Ok... Here is the code. Code is a bit long just follow the reloadData and delegate function of UItableview. thx in advance

```
@interface HMPeopleController ()

@property(nonatomic, retain)  UIPopoverController *popOverHMPeople;

@end

@implementation HMPeopleController
@synthesize peopleCell,hmpeopleController,storedArrayForContacts;
@synthesize btnPeople;
@synthesize addingContactToPeopleList;
@synthesize popOverHMPeople,popOverEmail;
@synthesize attendees, btnIsHidden;
@synthesize peopleTableView,attendeeToBeAdded, meetingSummary, atendeeList, sortedArray,btnAddEmail,attendeeCount;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{

    [hmpeopleController release];
    [popOverEmail release];
    [self.peopleTableView release];
    [addingContactToPeopleList release];

    [attendees release];

    [attendeeCount release];
    [sortedArray release];
    [self setAttendeeToBeAdded:nil];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
          AppDelegate *    appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if (appDelegate.joinOnlyMode) {
        btnAddEmail.hidden=YES;
    }

    content = [AttendeesHeaderGenerator wordsFromLetters];
    indices = [[content valueForKey:@"headerTitle"] retain];
    self.sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadData:) name:@"reload-data" object:nil];


       int totalOnline=0;

    for (HMAttendee *ha in [HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers) {
        if (ha.userStatus) {
            totalOnline++;
        }
    }

    attendeeCount = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 5, 22, 21)];    
    attendeeCount.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",totalOnline];
    [ attendeeCount setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor] ];
    [attendeeCount setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:attendeeCount];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneFromHmpeople:) name:@"doneFromHmpeople" object:nil];
    AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if(!app.joinOnlyMode)
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contacts" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(addContactBtnPressed:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

        [rightButton release];

        UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(addEmailHandler:)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
        [leftButton release];
    }
    UILabel *lb=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,5,55, 21)];

    [lb setText:@"Online"];
    [lb setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lb setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:lb];
    [lb release];

    UIImageView *onlineIcon=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-onn.png"] ];
    onlineIcon.frame=CGRectMake(98, 0, 32, 32);
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:onlineIcon]; 




    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    //  self.title=@"Addtendees";
}

-(IBAction)DonePressed:(id)sender{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hideatendeelist" object:nil];
}


-(void) reloadData:(id) sender
{

    if (self.view.tag == 555) {
        int users  = [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers count];
        numberOfRecords = users == 0 ? 1:users;
    }
    else
    {
        int users  = [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers count];
        if (users == numberOfRecords || (users-numberOfRecords) < 0) {
            [btnPeople setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"People", nil)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            //relalocate resources.

            [btnPeople setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%d)",NSLocalizedString(@"People",nil),users-numberOfRecords] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
            int totalOnline=0;
    for (HMAttendee *ha in [HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers) {
        if (ha.userStatus) {
            totalOnline++;
        }
    }

    attendeeCount.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",totalOnline];
    [sortedArray removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"%i",[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsersForTb.count);
    int total=[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsersForTb.count;

    for (int i=0; i<total; i++) {
        //        HMAttendee *at = [[HMAttendee alloc] init];
        HMAttendee *at = [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsersForTb objectAtIndex:i ];
        [sortedArray addObject:at];
    }

    [self.peopleTableView reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{


    attendeeCount = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(contactsSelected:)
                                                 name:@"contactsSelected"
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(hideAttendePopOver)
                                                 name:@"hideatendeePopOver"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    if ([[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsersForTb count] > 0) {
        NSArray *attendeeSecArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsersForTb];
        self.sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[attendeeSecArray sectionedArrayUsingProperty:@"strName"]];
        return [sortedArray count];  
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    //    int count = [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers count];
    //    int rowsInSec = 0;
    //    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    //        HMAttendee* attdee = [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers objectAtIndex:i];    
    //        if ([[[content objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"headerTitle"] isEqualToString:[attdee.strName substringToIndex:1]]){
    //            rowsInSec++;
    //            NSLog(@"Number of rows in section are %d", rowsInSec);
    //            
    //        }
    //    }

    NSArray *sectionArray = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionArray count];


    // return count == 0?1:count;
    //return rowsInSec;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    int count = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count];



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"[Presenter]", nil);
    }


    if (count == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentUser.strName;
    }
    else 
    { 

        HMAttendee* attdee = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = attdee.strName;
        if(attdee.userStatus)
        {

            UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
            img.frame=CGRectMake(280, (cell.frame.size.height/2)/2, 16,16);

            [cell addSubview:img];
            [img release];
            //       cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
            //      cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(280, cell.imageView.frame.origin.y, cell.imageView.image.size.width, cell.imageView.image.size.height);

        }
        else
        {

            UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"]];
            img.frame=CGRectMake(280,(cell.frame.size.height/2)/2, 16,16);

            [cell addSubview:img];
            [img release];
            //         cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(280, cell.imageView.frame.origin.y, cell.imageView.image.size.width, cell.imageView.image.size.height);
        }
    }
    return cell;
}




#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

-(IBAction)addContactBtnPressed:(id)sender{


    if ([self.popOverHMPeople isPopoverVisible]) {

        [self.popOverHMPeople dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    } 
    else
    {

        AddPeopleViewController *addPeopleController = nil;
        addPeopleController =[[AddPeopleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddPeopleViewController" bundle:nil];
        addPeopleController.delegate=self;


        myContactsViewController *addressbookController=[[myContactsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"myContactsViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                       initWithRootViewController:addressbookController];

        [self setPopOverHMPeople:[[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav]autorelease]];

        self.popOverHMPeople.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake( 300,500);

        //    if ([self.popOverHMPeople isPopoverVisible]) {
        //        
        //        [self.popOverHMPeople dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        //        
        //    } 
        //    else
        //    {

        CGRect bound;
        //bound=showAddressBookBtn.bounds;
        // bound.origin.x = 720;
        // bound.origin.y = 25;
        [self.popOverHMPeople presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
        //            }


    }
}


-(void) refresh
{
    [btnPeople setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"People" , nil)forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    int count = [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers count];
    numberOfRecords =  ( count== 0) ? 1:count;

    //add new added attendee


    for (HMAttendee* attendee in attendeeToBeAdded){

        NSMutableArray *storeArray =  [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting arrMeetingUsers];
        BOOL found=NO;
        for (HMAttendee *storeAtted in storeArray) {

            if ([attendee.strName isEqualToString:storeAtted.strName]) {
                found=YES;
            }
        }

        if(!found)
            [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers addObject:attendee];
    }

    [peopleTableView reloadData];

}

-(void) customDataInitialization
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadData:) name:@"reload-data" object:nil];
    numberOfRecords = 1;

}


- (void)ContactsSelected:(NSMutableArray *)contacts {

    NSLog(@"%d@",[[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers count]);
    [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers addObjectsFromArray:attendees];
    NSLog(@"%d@",[[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers count]);

    [peopleTableView reloadData];    



}

- (void)doneFromHmpeople:(NSNotification *)notification{

    if(popOverEmail.popoverVisible )
        [popOverEmail dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];


    //    [self refresh];


}

- (IBAction)addEmailHandler:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{


    if ([popOverEmail isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popOverEmail dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else {

        hmpeopleController = [[HMPeopleControllerAddEmail alloc]initWithNibName:@"HMPeopleControllerAddEmail" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController  *     navEmail=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:hmpeopleController];
        popOverEmail=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:navEmail];

        [popOverEmail setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(hmpeopleController.view.frame.size.width, hmpeopleController.view.frame.size.height)];

        [popOverEmail presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    }


}

- (BOOL)emailChecker:(NSString *)testStr{

    NSError *error=nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc]initWithPattern:@"[a-zA-Z_.0-9]+(@){1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\.){1}[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:&error];    
    //      NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc]initWithPattern:@"[a-zA-Z]+" options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:&error];


    int matche=[regex numberOfMatchesInString:testStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,testStr.length)];

    NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:testStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testStr length])];

    if (matche<=0) {
        return NO;
    }


    for ( NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches )
    {
        NSString* matchText = [testStr substringWithRange:[match range]];
        if(![matchText isEqualToString:testStr])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@ =In valid",matchText);
            return NO;
        }
        else if([matchText isEqualToString:testStr])  {
            NSLog(@"%@",matchText);
            return YES;
        }

    }


    return nil;

}

- (void)contactsSelected:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    attendees =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
    storedArrayForContacts=[dict objectForKey:@"key"];



    NSMutableString *attendeesCanntBeAdded=[[NSMutableString alloc]init]; 

    int count=[[dict objectForKey:@"key"] count];
    if (count==0) {
        [self.popOverHMPeople dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }
    NSMutableString* xmlDataString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    [self setAttendeeToBeAdded:nil];

    attendeeToBeAdded = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {

        HMAttendee *atn= [[HMAttendee alloc]init];

        atn.strName= [[[dict objectForKey:@"key"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Email"];


        if (![self emailChecker:atn.strName]) {
            [attendeesCanntBeAdded appendFormat:@"%@ ",atn.strName];
            continue;
        }



        if([atn.strName length] > 0)
        {

            if ([attendeeToBeAdded count] == 0) {
                NSMutableString* attendeeEmails = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                [attendeeEmails appendString:@"<EmailID>"];
                [attendeeEmails appendString:atn.strName];
                [attendeeEmails appendString:@"</EmailID>"];

                // [attendeeEmails appendString:atn.strName];
                NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:ADD_ATTENDEES_LIST_FORMAT,attendeeEmails];
                [xmlDataString appendString:data];
                // [attendeeEmails appendFormat:@"%@</EmailID><EmailID>",atn.strName];
                [attendeeEmails release];
            }else{
                NSMutableString* attendeeEmails = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                [attendeeEmails appendString:@"<EmailID>"];
                [attendeeEmails appendString:atn.strName];
                [attendeeEmails appendString:@"</EmailID>"];

                NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:ADD_ATTENDEES_LIST_FORMAT,attendeeEmails];

                [xmlDataString appendString:(NSMutableString*)email];
            }
            [attendeeToBeAdded addObject:atn];
        }
        [atn release];
    }   
    //[attendeeEmails appendString:@"</EmailID>"];
    if (attendeesCanntBeAdded.length>0) {
        NSString *st=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Following Emails are invalid:%@",attendeesCanntBeAdded];
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Skribbee" message:st delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [popOverEmail dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [attendeesCanntBeAdded release];
        [st release];

    }


    if ([HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.isAttendeePopOver == true && [attendeeToBeAdded count] > 0) {

        // NSString* aList = [NSString stringWithFormat:ADD_ATTENDEES_LIST_FORMAT,attendeeEmails];
        [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting addAttendee:@"" list:xmlDataString andDelegate:self];

    }

}
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    [self.popOverHMPeople dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    if(request.tag == ADD_ATTENDEE_REQUEST) {
        NSLog(@"%d",request.responseStatusCode);
        NSLog(@"%@",request.responseStatusMessage);
        NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"disableButton" object:nil];

        [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] hideActivityView];

        if(request.responseStatusCode == 200)
            //            [self hideAttendePopOver];
        {


            NSDictionary *dic=[request.responseString JSONValue ];
            NSString *rejectedEmails=[dic objectForKey:@"Description"];
            int startPtr,endPtr,offset;
            NSString *subStr;
            if(![rejectedEmails isEqualToString:@"OK"])
            {

                for (int i=0; i<rejectedEmails.length; i++) {
                    unichar c=[rejectedEmails characterAtIndex:i];
                    NSString *tmpStr=[[NSString alloc]initWithCharacters:&c length:1];

                    if([tmpStr isEqualToString:@"("])
                    {
                        startPtr=i;
                        startPtr++;
                    }
                    if([tmpStr isEqualToString:@")"])
                    {
                        endPtr=i;
                        offset=endPtr-startPtr;
                        subStr=[rejectedEmails substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPtr, offset)];
                        break;
                    }



                }//end for
                startPtr=0,endPtr=0,offset=0;
                NSMutableArray *tempMarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                //            NSData *data=[subStr dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
                //            NSString *textRev=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
                //            
                //            NSLog(@" Actual String.. %@",textRev);
                //            subStr=textRev;
                for (int i=0;i<subStr.length; i++) {
                    unichar c=[subStr characterAtIndex:i];
                    NSString *tmpStr=[[NSString alloc]initWithCharacters:&c length:1];
                    if(i == (subStr.length-1) )
                    {



                        int offset=i-startPtr+1;
                        NSString *subStr2=[subStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPtr, offset)];

                        if([subStr2 isEqualToString:@" "])
                            break;

                        NSMutableDictionary *tempDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

                        [tempDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Name"];
                        [tempDict setObject:subStr2 forKey:@"Email"];
                        [tempMarray addObject:tempDict];
                        startPtr=i+1;

                    }

                    if([tmpStr isEqualToString:@","])
                    {
                        int offset=i-startPtr;
                        NSString *subStr2=[subStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPtr, offset)];
                        NSMutableDictionary *tempDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

                        [tempDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Name"];
                        [tempDict setObject:subStr2 forKey:@"Email"];
                        [tempMarray addObject:tempDict];
                        startPtr=i+1;
                    }
                }
                NSMutableArray *tempArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:attendeeToBeAdded];

                for (NSDictionary *d2 in tempMarray) {
                    NSString *drstr=[d2 objectForKey:@"Email"];
                    drstr=[drstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                    for (HMAttendee *d3 in tempArr) {
                        NSString *d3str=[d3.strName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                        if([d3str isEqualToString:drstr])
                        {
                            [attendeeToBeAdded removeObject:d3];

                        }
                    }
                }

            }//end OK if
            NSString *code=[dic objectForKey:@"Code"];

            NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
            [self refresh];

            if([code isEqualToString:@"200.1"])
            {
                //                UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Skribbee" message:[dic objectForKey:@"Description"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                //                [alert show];
                //                [alert release];



            }
            else if([code isEqualToString:@"200"])
            {
                //            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Skribbee" message:@"Attendee Added Successfully!." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                //            [alert show];
                //            [alert release];
            }
        }
        else {

            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Skribbee" message:@"Your request was not completed successfully, please try again later!." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }

    }
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hideatendeelist" object:nil];
}

-(void)hideAttendePopOver{

    [self.popOverHMPeople dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: @MidhunMP NP, thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` you are returning 0. That's why it's not working.

Also the possible issue is if the `[sortedArray count]` is zero then also the numberOfSection will return 0. Hence the cellForRowAtIndexPath won't be called. Check the count of the array using NSLog.

```
NSlog(@"Array count %d", [sortedArray count]);
```

Change the method like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    if ([[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsersForTb count] > 0)
    {
        NSArray *attendeeSecArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsersForTb];
        self.sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[attendeeSecArray sectionedArrayUsingProperty:@"strName"]];
        return [sortedArray count];  
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but still the same

Comment: @what is the output of NSLog ?

Comment: k i solved this issue by making a new controller and copied the necessary code(only umcommented code) and it worked.... thx every one